# Flow of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging

How can we test the flow of the JavaScript files..?

How to do we go through flow of app step by step - in - JavaScript files including its event listeners...?

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: if you're in a browser, all the main browsers now provide built-in debugging tools, including a line-by-line code debugger. Just press F12. Chrome's debugger is probably the best for event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

Most Javascript debuggers support breakpoints. You can add them by clicking on the line numbers on the left of the code.

Chrome also has event listener breakpoints. Firebug seems to have it [coming up](http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html#event) sometime.

[image]

Comment: I am using Opera12. So how do I achieve it with dragonfly?

Comment: no my code doesn't work on chrome. Either Opera 12 or Opera Next are the supported browser.

Comment: They seem to be called event breakpoints in Opera http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/debugger/